# How to use MarkDown in a custom textarea field?

Tags: metabox, wp-editor, markdown

I've created a custom metabox with a textarea in it. How would I go about using Markdown in this textarea? I've seen some WP plugins but they seem to only be for the main editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a copy of [PHP Markdown](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown) and use it to parse the textarea contents before you save it:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Markdown' ) ) {
    require_once( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/markdown.php' );
}
$textarea_contents = Markdown::defaultTransform( $textarea_contents );
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed [ACF Custom Field WYSIWYG](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf-wordpress-wysiwyg-field) and [Markdown Extra](https://littoral.michelf.ca/code/php-markdown/php-markdown-extra-1.2.8.zip).

In `functions.php`, add code:

```
remove_filter( 'acf_the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'acf_the_content', 'wptexturize' );
add_filter( 'acf_the_content', 'Markdown' );
```

Every custom post field that uses `acf_the_content` will convert to Markdown. You can use the main content too:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'Markdown' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The best Markdown parser I've found so far is the [`Parsedown`](http://parsedown.org/). Something like this:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Parsedown' ) ) {
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/Parsedown.php' );
}

$parsedown = new Parsedown();
echo $parsedown->text( $content );
```

If you are dealing with a client this is the way to go, Parsedown is almost bulletproof.

Comment: 2020 : Thanks man ...